# How can I dismiss the keyboard programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I need a way of determining the `UITextField` that is currently selected in a view. Is this possible without passing a reference or tag?

To be more specific I need to be able to tell which `UITextField` is selected so that I can hide the keyboard. The reason I need this is because I want to create a `UIToolbar` to add to all the `UITextField`'s as an input accessory. On this `UIToolbar` I will add a 'Done' button, when pressed this should hide the keyboard for the currently selected `UITextField`.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific. Or show some code.

Comment: Ditto. What do you mean by _selected_?

Comment: I have added more details as per your request.

Comment: This question is rather old, but I updated it with an answer that doesn't require any extra coding. Just use `[self.view endEditing:YES]`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a delegate method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Apple Docs:

> This method notifies the delegate that the specified text field just
>   became the first responder. You can use this method to update your
>   delegate’s state information. For example, you might use this method
>   to show overlay views that should be visible while editing.

There is also a property:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isEditing) BOOL editing
```

Apple Docs:

> A Boolean value indicating whether the text field is currently in edit
>   mode. (read-only)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you want to know which `UITextField` is the first responder (which is the text field that gets input from the keyboard).

There is no public API for this (though there is a private API).  You can track which text field is the first responder manually using the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method of each text field's delegate, or you can use a little trickery to find the first responder at any time.

Here's the trick.  The `UIApplication` object knows which object is the first responder, and can send a message to it.  So you write a category like this on `UIResponder`:

### UIResponder+firstResponderHack.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIResponder (firstResponderHack)

+ (UIResponder *)firstResponderByHack;

@end
```

### UIResponder+firstResponderHack.m

```
#import "UIResponder+firstResponderHack.h"

@interface FirstResponderFinder : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIResponder *firstResponder;
@end

@implementation FirstResponderFinder
@synthesize firstResponder = _firstResponder;
@end

@implementation UIResponder (firstResponderHack)

- (void)putFirstResponderIntoFinder:(FirstResponderFinder *)finder {
    if (self.isFirstResponder)
        finder.firstResponder = self;
}

+ (UIResponder *)firstResponderByHack {
    FirstResponderFinder *finder = [FirstResponderFinder new];
    // Sending an action to nil sends it to the first responder.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(putFirstResponderIntoFinder:) to:nil from:finder forEvent:nil];
    return finder.firstResponder;
}

@end
```

Then you can find the first responder, and check whether it's a `UITextField`, like this:

```
UIResponder *firstResponder = [UIResponder firstResponderByHack];
if (firstResponder && [firstResponder isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)firstResponder;
    // do something with textField
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to dismiss the keyboard *without having to track the currently active control*, or iterating through all the available controls, or using a `UITextFieldDelegate`.

```
[self.view endEditing:YES]
```

From the docs:

> **endEditing:**
>
> Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to
>   resign the first responder status.
>       - (`BOOL`)endEditing:(`BOOL`)*force*
>
> **Parameters**
>   *force*
>  
>   Specify `YES` to force the first responder to resign, regardless of whether it wants to do
>   so. 
>   **Return Value**
>   `YES` if the view resigned the first responder status or `NO` if it did not.
>
> **Discussion**
>  
>   This method looks at the current view and its subview
>   hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder. If
>   it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If
>   the force parameter is set to `YES`, the text field is never even asked;
>   it is forced to resign.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an ivar for the UITextView in your header file:

```
UITextField *editingField;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UITextField *editingField;
```

Then,

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
{
    editingField = textField;

    // Whatever else you want to do 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that you need to diff the textFields without reference.
So, the recommended why is using **ObjectiveC runtime**.
It's pretty straight forward.
Firstly:

```
  #import <objc/runtime.h>
```

Then, define a char for its address:

```
   static char UITextFieldViewIdentifier;
```

Then set the identifier with something like this:

```
  objc_setValue(textField, &UITextFieldViewIdentifier, @"Identifier") //typing on a phone, not so sure about the expression
```

In the delegate method:

```
   NSString *identifier = objc_getObject(textField, &UITextFieldViewIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call this line where you want to dismiss the keyboard:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```