# How to get the currently active UITextField/UITextView and resignFirstResponder?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

Is it possible to get the currently active UITextField or UITextView in a UIView, so I can hide the keyboard with `[text resignFirstResponder];`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine the UITextField currently selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956704/how-can-i-determine-the-uitextfield-currently-selected)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As of iOS 2.0 and later, there is an easy way to dismiss the keyboard without having to track the currently active control, or iterating through all the available controls, or using a `UITextFieldDelegate`.

```
[self.view endEditing:YES]
```

From the docs:

> **endEditing:**
>
> Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to
>   resign the first responder status.
>       - (`BOOL`)endEditing:(`BOOL`)*force*
>
> **Parameters**
>   *force*
>  
>   Specify `YES` to force the first responder to resign, regardless of whether it wants to do
>   so. 
>   **Return Value**
>   `YES` if the view resigned the first responder status or `NO` if it did not.
>
> **Discussion**
>  
>   This method looks at the current view and its subview
>   hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder. If
>   it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If
>   the force parameter is set to `YES`, the text field is never even asked;
>   it is forced to resign.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to directly get what object is the current first responder (that I know of, at least) without testing them individually. What you can do is to create a method containing all subviews which could conceivably be the active first responder, as follows:

```
- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    if (myTextField1.isFirstResponder) {
        [myTextField1 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (myTextField2.isFirstResponder) {
        [myTextField2 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (myTextField3.isFirstResponder) {
        [myTextField3 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (myTextField4.isFirstResponder) {
        [myTextField4 resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

In reality, though, I tend to do it this way, without first testing whether a particular UIView is the current first responder, and don't think there is any appreciable performance hit/issue (that I've noticed anyway):

```
- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    //Send resignFirstResponder message to all possible first responders...
    [myTextField1 resignFirstResponder];
    [myTextField2 resignFirstResponder];
    [myTextField3 resignFirstResponder];
    [myTextField4 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: This is not necessary, [self.view endEditing:YES]; will do

Answer (score 5):

This swift code works in finding the first responder:

```
func findActiveResponderFrame(view:UIView)->UIView?{
  if view.isFirstResponder() {
    return view
  } else {
    for sub in view.subviews {
      if let subView = sub as? UIView,
             found = findActiveResponderFrame(subView){
        return found
      }
    }
  }
  return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can following if you specifically want to fetch responder text field.
[Get the current first responder without using a private API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/how-do-i-legally-get-the-current-first-responder-on-the-screen-on-an-iphone)

you can also use following code if you only want to dismiss active text field keyboard-

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
 }
```

Comment: refer following for text view- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key

Answer (score 0):

> Update for Swift 3

This function hides the keyboard of any active textfield in Swift 3:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918732/how-to-determine-which-textfield-is-active-swift/50341397#50341397). 
I wrote a basic form creation library that handles this and validation. It's called [Swift POP Form](https://github.com/bikisDesign/Swift_POP_Form)! 
It doesn't use `tags` but rather sets a datasource that contains fields and uses `indexPathForCell` to query which is the active textfield. Check out the source code for more!

edit:
Or as requested heres a snippet from it. This form uses `UITextFields` embedded in `UITableViewCells`:

```
extension PopFormViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

  func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    guard let cell = textField.superview as? PopFormTableViewCell else {
      fatalError() }

    guard let currentIndex = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
      fatalError("cell does not exist") }

    let nextIndex = IndexPath(row: currentIndex.row + 1, section: currentIndex.section)
    let isLastField = viewModel.dataSource.fields.count == nextIndex.row

    if isLastField {
      cell.textField.resignFirstResponder()
      if shouldValidateOnLastFieldReturnKeyTap {
        validator.validate(self)
      }
      return true
    }

    guard let nextCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: nextIndex) as? PopFormTableViewCell else {
      fatalError() }

    nextCell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be more useful if you could share the code here.