# How to determine which textfield is active swift

Tags: ios, swift

I cant figure out which `UITextField` is currently active so i can clear its text if they hit cancel on a `UIBarButtonItem`. Here is my code. There is a view with a `UIPickerView`,`UIToolBar` and two bar button items. The cancel item has an action that will clear its text only i cant figure out how to get the correct `UITextField`.

I've tried these both:

```
@IBAction func cancelText(sender: AnyObject) {


    if self.truckYear.editing == true{

        println("truckYear")

        clearText(self.truckYear)
    } else if self.truckMake.editing == true{

        clearText(self.truckMake)
    }
}
@IBAction func doneText(sender: AnyObject) {

    pickerView.hidden = true
}


func clearText(textField:UITextField){

    println("in clear text")

    textField.text = nil
}
```

And:

```
@IBAction func cancelText(sender: AnyObject) {


    if self.truckYear.isFirstResponder(){

        println("truckYear")

        clearText(self.truckYear)
    } else if self.truckMake.isFirstResponder(){

        clearText(self.truckMake)
    }
}
@IBAction func doneText(sender: AnyObject) {

    pickerView.hidden = true
}


func clearText(textField:UITextField){

    println("in clear text")

    textField.text = nil
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can declare a `UITextField` property in your class, and assign the current text field to it in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`.
Then you can just call this text field whenever you need to.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

   var activeTextField = UITextField()

   // Assign the newly active text field to your activeTextField variable
   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        self.activeTextField = textField
   }

   // Call activeTextField whenever you need to
   func anotherMethod() {

       // self.activeTextField.text is an optional, we safely unwrap it here
       if let activeTextFieldText = self.activeTextField.text {
             print("Active text field's text: \(activeTextFieldText)")
             return;
       }

       print("Active text field is empty")
   }
}
```

Comment: So could I use that and then in the UIBarButtonItem Action just say clearText(self.activeTextField) ?

Comment: Yes, you would be able to do that.

Comment: Ok I just tried it and no errors but the text isn't being set to nill. This is my code, ` func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        
        self.activeTextfield = textField
    }
    
    @IBAction func cancelText(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        println("action fired")
        
        self.activeTextfield.text = nil
        self.pickerView.hidden = true
    }
    @IBAction func doneText(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        pickerView.hidden = true
    }`

Comment: In your `cancelText(...)` method, could you add `NSLog("text in activeTextField : %@", self.activeTextField.text)` before trying to clear it ? It should show you the content of this text field. Also, try to clear your text like that : self.activeTextfield.text = ""

Comment: Ya I will add it, I put a println statement in the textFieldDidBeginEditing and its not making it into that method. Also how did you post code in the comment, I used the backticks but nothing happened. If I set the text to nil it will put the placeholder text back in, will it still do that if I set it to ""?

Comment: Here's the output `2015-06-18 09:31:15.940 LTmobile[18867:4494135] text in activeTextField : `

Comment: Did you set the delegate property of your textfield to "self" ( `myTextField.delegate = self` ? Did you assign the delegate object `UITextField` to your viewcontroller ? ( As you can see in the first line of my answer ( `, UITextFieldDelegate` ). I use "`" to set my code.

Comment: And normally, setting your textfield.text to nil should work, I definitely think that you should read some documentations about delegation as Almo said.

Comment: Yes the activeTextfield is delegate, all my textfields are delegate on the scene and I have the UITextFieldDelegate protocol in the view controller. Its just weird that the delegate method didBeginEditing isnt firing because I have the touchesBegan delegate method working just fine.

Comment: Can you post the whole code for your view controller ?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for all your help. So come to find out I was already using didBeginEditing further down, (I know Im a noob), and then your code worked brilliantly. Thank you!

Comment: Can I do this in Cocoa by just replacing the UI with NS?

Comment: I guess so yes, why don't you try and tell us?

Answer (score 24):

In swift 4:

you can get the active UITextField like that

```
extension UIView {
func getSelectedTextField() -> UITextField? {

    let totalTextFields = getTextFieldsInView(view: self)

    for textField in totalTextFields{
        if textField.isFirstResponder{
            return textField
        }
    }

    return nil

}

func getTextFieldsInView(view: UIView) -> [UITextField] {

    var totalTextFields = [UITextField]()

    for subview in view.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let textField = subview as? UITextField {
            totalTextFields += [textField]
        } else {
            totalTextFields += getTextFieldsInView(view: subview)
        }
    }

    return totalTextFields
}}
```

and then you call it like that

```
let current = view.getSelectedTextField()
```

Answer (score 14):

In order to improve @Reimond's answer **Swift 4**

```
extension UIView {
    var textFieldsInView: [UITextField] {
        return subviews
            .filter ({ !($0 is UITextField) })
            .reduce (( subviews.compactMap { $0 as? UITextField }), { summ, current in
                return summ + current.textFieldsInView
        })
    }
    var selectedTextField: UITextField? {
        return textFieldsInView.filter { $0.isFirstResponder }.first
    }
}
```

usage:

`view.selectedTextField`

Answer (score 1):

you can assign a tag to all your text feild and in 
textFieldDidBeginEditing 
check your current textFeild.tag and it's clear witch textfeild is in use .

Comment: Please consider writing the code that will do the job rather than giving a random description on how to di it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate:

```
optional func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
```

This will tell you when the active textfield finishes editing, and `textField` will contain a pointer to the one that's no longer going to be active.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to implement that into that action?

Comment: I really recommend learning how to implement delegate methods. You'll have no end of trouble with the Cocoa API if you don't have that figured out.

Comment: I implement some delegate methods but Im fairly new to swift so I dont have all the pieces to the puzzle but i'll take a shot at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// Finds the textField that is the first responder in a view hierarchy
func findActiveTextField(in subviews: [UIView], textField: inout UITextField?) {

    guard textField == nil else { return }

    for view in subviews {
        if let tf = view as? UITextField, view.isFirstResponder {
            textField = tf
            break
        }
        else if !view.subviews.isEmpty {
            findActiveTextField(in: view.subviews, textField: &textField)
        }
    }
}

// Usage
var aView: UIView = UIView()
var activeField : UITextField?
findActiveTextField(in: aView.subviews, textField: &activeField)
```

Comment: `Use of unresolved identifier 'activeField'` please fix this

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library to handle basic Form Creation [Swift Pop Form](https://github.com/bikisDesign/Swift_POP_Form). 
It doesn't use `tags` but rather sets a datasource that contains fields and uses `indexPathForCell` to query which is the active textfield. Check out the source code for more!