# How can I reach UITextfield in subviews in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, textfield, subview

Here is the objects hierarchy in my ViewController in Main.Storyboard

[image: all objects]

Button same size with superview. I would like to close the keyboard with the button click action that's why I wrote this code scope:

```
@IBAction func btnCloseKeyboardClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("A")
    for viewItem in self.view.subviews
    {
        print("B")
        if (viewItem is UITextField)
        {
            print("C")
            let tField = viewItem as! UITextField
            tField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

but it does not close the keyboard means I don't see `print("C")`

[I solved this problem like in this link but I would like to ask above situation also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918732/how-to-determine-which-textfield-is-active-swift/48646952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one textfield in your view and want to dismiss keyboard for that, the simple way is to call `view.endEditing(true)` in your button action

Comment: My friend Thanks but Let's assume I have at least 2 textfield objects in my page. That's why I wrote the 'for scope' in button action. I can write your code but first I need to see print("C") code line. This is the problem. @Mac3n

Comment: for dismiss the keyboard in this way you don't need to check for the view class type, just in your IBAction method call `view.endEditing(true)` below print("A")

Comment: it works after I remove if (viewItem is UITextField) like you say. But How can I check the viewItem is UITextField or not? Is this checking not necessary?

Comment: if the purpose of action is dismiss the keyboard from view, it’s not necessary to check view type because endEditing method belongs to view not textfield